# The wrong app launches after running my ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode11, ios13.6

I am a beginner learning ios development. I have created 2 basic apps so far (screenshot), and whenever I try to run the 2nd app (I AM Rich) either on xcode's simulator or on my iPhone, it launches but after 2-3 seconds it switches to the other app (Hello World). I have no idea why is this happening, and I could not find similar issues on the internet.

I am using *MacOS 10.15.5*, *Xcode 11.6*, *ios 13.6*

Your help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you try creating a new project and running it and seeing if the same thing happens?

Comment: I have created a third app, it does not look like it suffers from the same issue.

Comment: Posting your AppDelegate and ViewController code would help.

Comment: Your question lacks debugging details. The only thing I see is a screenshot of two folders. Nothing else. Please, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.